# Autofocus to input when user starts typing even not selecting the input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to autofocus an input, after the user starts typing, even the cursor is not on the input when the user is typing.

I am having difficulty with the JavaScript.

```
$(function(){
    $("#focusa").focus();
});
```

I tried using this, but I don't know how to actually make it interact with the HTML.

Comment: Fixed grammar and clarified a bit, but you still need to show your HTML and how you're trying to make it work on the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
$(window).keypress(function()
{
    $("#field").focus();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="field" type="text">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yyvw065m/

Answer (score 1):

You want cursor to appear in input box once the page is loaded. So for this you can do following:

Using HTML: `<input id= "focusa" type=text autofocus>`

Using Javascript: You have to call onload function. Here is small snippet of code that can help you. You have to put script tag inside the html body after the input field.

```
<script>
    window.onload= function(){
         var inputText = document.getElementById("focusa").focus();
       }
</script>
```

Here is a link for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp